# How to filter pivot table by keeping only rows with at least one value over 0?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I don't know if my question is really clear, so I'll develop here:

I have a pivot table, and I would like to filter out every row which has no value equal or above 1.

Example:

| label | value 1 | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 0 |
| b | 0 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 1 |
| d | 1 | 0 |
| e | 0 | 0 |

I would like to be able to filter it to this :

| label | value 1 | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | 0 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 1 |
| d | 1 | 0 |

is it possible with Excel?
I searched everywhere and I couldn't find anything usable with a pivot table...

Comment: Could you add a calculated total of the values and then suppress rows with a total equal to zero?

Answer (score 0):

### How to filter pivot rows

To do this, we can iterate over `PivotItems` from `RowFields` and check the corresponding `DataRange` for compliance with the stated requirement. For those not suitable, set `Visible = False`

To filter rows with no values equal to or greater than 1 we can use this code:

```vb
Sub Macro_FilterPivot()
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim item As PivotItem
    With ActiveSheet
        If .PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set pvt = .PivotTables(1)
        For Each item In pvt.RowFields(1).PivotItems
            item.Visible = .Evaluate("OR(" & item.DataRange.Address & ">=1)")
        Next item
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the time it would take to filter data is too long for what i want to do...

Comment: @Tartyflaite Here is a rough but quick solution. Put a formula `=OR(B2:C2 >= 1)` at the very end of the first data row (in terms of your table it's `D2`) and drag it down to the last row of your pivot. Apply autofilter in `D1` and choose `TRUE`. Actually, it's not a solution, just a hack.